# Error wrap/unwrap && type checking with errors.Is()

Tags: go, error-handling, wrapper, trace

I am checking through an error trace in Go v1.13 Go v1.14. Why does it appear that only error implementations without parameters or with value receivers can be found with `errors.Is()`? This means that an error implementation capable of wrapping must have a value receiver in order to be able to be found with `errors.Is()`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
)

type someAtomicError struct {}
func (e *someAtomicError) Error() string { return "Hi!" }
func checkAtomicError() {
    e := &someAtomicError{}
    e2 := fmt.Errorf("whoa!: %w", e)
    e2IsE := errors.Is(e2, &someAtomicError{})
    fmt.Println("atomic error trace ---\t\t", e2, "\t\t--- is traceable: ", e2IsE)
}


type someWrapperError struct {
    Msg string
    Err error
}
func (e someWrapperError) Error() string { return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %v", e.Msg, e.Err) }
func (e someWrapperError) Unwrap() error { return e.Err }
func checkWrapperError() {
    e := someWrapperError{"Hi!", nil}
    e2 := fmt.Errorf("whoa!: %w", e)
    e2IsE := errors.Is(e2, someWrapperError{"Hi!", nil})
    fmt.Println("wrapper error trace ---\t\t", e2, "\t--- is traceable: ", e2IsE)
}


type somePointerWrapperError struct {
    Msg string
    Err error
}
func (e *somePointerWrapperError) Error() string { return fmt.Sprintf("%s: %v", e.Msg, e.Err) }
func (e *somePointerWrapperError) Unwrap() error { return e.Err }
func checkPointerWrapperError() {
    e := &somePointerWrapperError{"Hi!", nil}
    e2 := fmt.Errorf("whoa!: %w", e)
    e2IsE := errors.Is(e2, &somePointerWrapperError{"Hi!", nil})
    fmt.Println("pointer wrapper error trace ---\t", e2, "\t--- is traceable: ", e2IsE)
}


func main() {
    checkAtomicError()
    checkWrapperError() 
    checkPointerWrapperError()
}

//atomic error trace ---         whoa!: Hi!         --- is traceable:  true
//wrapper error trace ---        whoa!: Hi!: <nil>  --- is traceable:  true
//pointer wrapper error trace ---    whoa!: Hi!: <nil>  --- is traceable:  false
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-hSukZ-gii2

It seems that any difference in parameters, including in the wrapped error parameter, `Err`, will result in the type being unable to be found with `errors.Is()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason you are getting `false` while trying to find one error within another via `errors.Is` is because - while the two errors may have the same field values - they are two different memory pointers:

```
e  := &somePointerWrapperError{"Hi!", nil}
e2 := &somePointerWrapperError{"Hi!", nil} // e2 != e

ew := fmt.Errorf("whoa!: %w", e)

errors.Is(ew, e)  // true
errors.Is(ew, e2) // false - because `ew` wraps `e` not `e2`
```

So how to detect this "type" of error *and* get its value: use `errors.As` instead:

```
e := &somePointerWrapperError{"Hi!", nil}
e2 := fmt.Errorf("whoa!: %w", e)

var ev *somePointerWrapperError

if errors.As(e2, &ev) {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ev) // &somePointerWrapperError{Msg:"Hi!", Err:error(nil)}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/CttKThLasXD

Answer (score 8):

Remotely related, but maybe it helps someone: It took me some time to realize that `errors.As(...)` actually expects a double pointer to the target, while `errors.Is(...)` doesn't:

```
var _ error = (*CustomError)(nil) // ensure CustomError implements error

type CustomError struct {
    msg string
}

func (e CustomError) Error() string {
    return e.msg
}

func main() {
    err := &CustomError{"Hello, world!"} // Methods return pointers to errors, allowing them to be nil
    
    var eval *CustomError

    as := errors.As(err, &eval) // yes, that's **CustomError
    asFaulty := errors.As(err, eval) // no compile error, so it wrongly seems okay
    is := errors.Is(err, eval) // that's just *CustomError

    fmt.Printf("as: %t, asFaulty: %t, is: %t", as, asFaulty, is) // as: true, asFaulty: false, is: true
}
```